# Get Text Domain For Transalation

Tags: translation

Is there a function which can be used to get the themes text-domain?

For example, if i want to provide this code to users without them needing to swap out the text-domain, can this be done, rather than this :

```
register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Widget Area', 'twentynineteen' ),
            'id'            => 'widget-id',
        ));
```

Use something like this so they don't need to change the text-domain to match the theme they are using :

```
 register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name'          => __( 'Widget Area', get_text_domain() ),
            'id'            => 'widget-id',
        ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The text domain needs to be hard coded, otherwise it can't be read by localization tools which parse the code without executing it.

See this note from the [Internationalization documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#add-text-domain-to-strings)

> The text domain should be passed as a string to the localization
> functions instead of a variable. It allows parsing tools to
> differentiate between text domains. Example of what not to do:
>
> ```
> __( 'Translate me.' , $text_domain );
> ```

The string itself also cannot be a variable or function for the same reason.